# Capture Video as well as Images in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod

I am using ImagePickerController for Video Capturing. I need to save the capturing video as image also.

So I selected AVCaptureSession for capturing Images. I'm not able to run AVCaptureSession as well as ImagePickerController. So I need to give the ImagePickerController as input to the AVCaptureSession.

But I don't know how to do that. Please Help me.. and suggest me for the right way.

Comment: See if this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023214/uiimagepickercontroller-getting-image-capture-from-video

Comment: can you please refer me any other link which have some elaborate coding of this one.... please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found only these two. Hope its helps.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/24025-uiimagepickercontroller-videorecording-iphone-3gs.html

[UIImagePickerController: Getting image capture from video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023214/uiimagepickercontroller-getting-image-capture-from-video)

Comment: The first link is nothing just like capturing a picture and the second one is already you given. I used ffmpeg for converting video into images. But it taking at most 2.15 mins for converting a Minute video. Do u have any idea about that to increase the conversion speed. That would be great help...

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue.. I did work on image and video and used below code for image capturing:

```
- (void) snapImage: (id) sendern
{
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES]; 

}
```

And for video recording i used below code:

```
- (void) recordVideo: (id) sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
    ipc.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
    ipc.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f; // 30 seconds
    ipc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"];
    // ipc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.movie", @"public.image", nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES]; 
}
```

Hope will help you both code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (IBAction) useCamera: (id)sender
    {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker
                                    animated:YES];
            newMedia = YES;
        }
    }

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
    {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
    }

}
-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apple docs and sample code related to AVFoundation has several mistakes. See [iOS 4: Take photos with live preview using AVFoundation](http://blog.red-glasses.com/?p=162) for code that actually captures images from a live preview.

Comment: What I'm try to do is Capture the Video as well as Capture the video frame as Images.. I used ffmpeg for convert video into images. But it take more time. I need to reduce the time. All expert suggest AVAssetReader for convert video into image. Can you please send me the link or code for converting video into image (which do some faster work)... Please...